# How to change HikariCP logging time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am working on a Spring Boot project and I can see connection pool details thanks to below codes:

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

Also, here is my HikariCP configuration codes:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
```

HikariCP housekeeper logs each 30 second. I want to increase this logging time.(2 min,5 min etc.)
Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks your answers.